# SSL Needed Between Services on Same Server?

Tags: ssl

I have an XBMCbuntu set up which previously had public-facing, password protected webservices: xbmc, sickbeard, couchpotato, sabnzbd. I connected to all of them over https to avoid sending my password and other info in the clear.

Now I'm looking into Maraschino, which is a front-end for all of those services. It makes API calls to those other services, putting all my controls in one place. My question is, would I gain any benefit by encrypting the API calls between Maraschino and the other services, when they are all on the same server. Would there be any detriment to doing so?

Finally, I encrypted Maraschino by denying its port to outside access, and then reverse proxying it from port 443. In Nginx it looks like this:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name [redacted];

location / {
    proxy_pass  http://[redacted]:7000;
}

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;


}
```

It appears to work (Firefox lets me know my certificate is not signed by a valid authority, and displays the lock in the url bar). Is this adequate?

Comment: 'Adequate' for what? What are your requirements? What is your threat model? What's the point, in other words?

Comment: @EJP The point behind the SSL encryption is to prevent casual MITM attacks. I have no illusions about protecting myself from any serious, concerted effort, but someone who sniffed my password could cause quite a bit of nuisance on my server.

Comment: Why do you think you need to protect against MITM attacks from within the server? Isn't it physically secure? Do the attackers have logins? Are they able to deploy arbitrary software in it? Again, what's the threat model?

Comment: That's really kind of my question: Do requests between services on the same machine ever leave the machine? Are they vulnerable in any way to outside sniffing or attacks?